# Printing user given values in Fibonacci sequence in R

Tags: r, function, fibonacci

I am trying to make function that prints values of Fibonacci sequence that are under user given value (n). So input 8 will return values (1,1,2,3,5,8)

```
Fib<-  function(n){
 v=NULL
 v[1]<-1
 v[2]<-1 
 for(i in 3:n){
     v[i]<-v[i-1]+v[i-2]
     while(v[i]<=n){
         print(v)
         break}}}
```

input

```
fib(8)
[1] 1 1 2
[1] 1 1 2 3
[1] 1 1 2 3 5
[1] 1 1 2 3 5 8
```

I would want only the last one printed out.
I also tried it with `append(v,v[i])` but haven't got that working so it would return only values below n.
Will appreciate any tips given.

Comment: Take the print out of the for loop.  Put it after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one only while without break to reach it:

```
Fib<-  function(n){
  v=NULL
  v[1]<-1
  v[2]<-1 
  i<-2
  while(v[i]<=n)
  {
    i<-i+1
    v[i]<-as.numeric(v[i-1])+as.numeric(v[i-2])
  }
  print(v[1:length(v)-1])
}
```

This is your desired output:

```
Fib(8)
[1] 1 1 2 3 5 8
```

Comment: Why `Fib(8)` does not return the last row showed in OP output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a recursive approach (if you want, you can modify this to let the limit be an input, but I like it better this way to conserve stack space ):

```
V = c(1,1)
Limit = 10

fib = function(n){
        if(n > L){
          print(V)
          return()
        }else{
          n = V[(length(V)-1) : length(V)] %>% sum
          V <<- c(V,n)
          return(fib(n))
        }
}
fib(0)
```